# how to extract a string for a list that contain a integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests, pycharm

I want to extract the string from my list. This is my list.

```
[['Lions 3', ' Snakes 3'], ['Tarantulas 1', ' FC Awesome 0'],
 ['Lions 1', ' FC Awesome 1'], ['Tarantulas 3', ' Snakes 1'],
 ['Lions 4', ' Grouches 0']]
```

This is what I have tried:
The if statement is inside a for loop to iterate through the list.

```
if items[0][-1] == items[1][-1]:
    print('Draw for {} & {}'.format(items[0][:4], items[1][1:]))
```

Output:

> Draw for Lions 3 &  Snakes 3

Desired output:

> Draw for Lions  &  Snakes

without the integers

Comment: The -1 is to print the last item in that list like 3:3 but I want to print the string without the the integer

Comment: You could replace 'items[0][:4]' with 'items[0][:4][:-1]' to omit the integer(assuming that it is always and only the last character in the string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting would grab all the digits, not just last and help you handle high scores such as 11, 12 ... . Right split helps handle multiword teams like 'FC Awesome'.

```
for left, right in lst:
    lteam, lscore = left.strip().rsplit(' ', 1)
    rteam, rscore = right.strip().rsplit(' ', 1) 

    if lscore == rscore:
         print('Draw for {} & {}'.format(lteam, rteam))
```

Strip deletes trailing or initial spaces.

Comment: This is much simpler and more understandable to me as I am new to coding

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re

reg_exp = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z]+")
my_string = "String 3"
reg_exp.search(my_string).group(0) // outputs 'String'
```

of course you need to adapt this to your loop to extract the desired string

Comment: it would fail to  treat "FC Awesome 4"

Comment: Yes you are right maybe `r"[A-Za-z ]+"` would be a more precise pattern

Comment: yup, that is better, you might wish to to remove the trailing or preceding spaces

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can try.

```
>>> 
>>> items = [['Lions 3', ' Snakes 3'], ['Tarantulas 1', ' FC Awesome 0'], ['Lions 1', ' FC Awesome 1'], ['Tarantulas 3', ' Snakes 1'], ['Lions 4', ' Grouches 0']]
>>> 
>>> output = [[s.split()[0] for s in item] for item in items]
>>> output
[['Lions', 'Snakes'], ['Tarantulas', 'FC'], ['Lions', 'FC'], ['Tarantulas', 'Snakes'], ['Lions', 'Grouches']]
>>>
```

Finally, this is what you can try to get your o/p.

```
>>> for item in output:
...     print('Draw for {} & {}'.format(item[0], item[1]))
... 
Draw for Lions & Snakes
Draw for Tarantulas & FC
Draw for Lions & FC
Draw for Tarantulas & Snakes
Draw for Lions & Grouches
>>>
```

Comment: Now I need to assign the winning team with 3 points and draw 1:1 then lose 0

Comment: Thank you all for your help I highly appreciate itt

Answer (score 0):

Jumping to some conclusions:

```py
matches = [['Lions 3', 'Snakes 3'], 
           ['Tarantulas 1', 'FC Awesome 0'],
           ['Lions 1', 'FC Awesome 1'], 
           ['Tarantulas 3', 'Snakes 1'],
           ['Lions 4', 'Grouches 0']]

def split_team_and_score(team_and_score):
    team, _, raw_score = team_and_score.rpartition(" ") 
    return team, int(raw_score)

for team_and_score_1, team_and_score_2 in matches:
    team1, score1 = split_team_and_score(team_and_score_1)
    team2, score2 = split_team_and_score(team_and_score_2)
    if score1 == score2:
        print('Draw for {} & {}'.format(team1, team2))
```